# How to delete added attestation in google cloud platform's kubernetes engine image authorization process

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-kubernetes-engine

I have added an attestation on google cloud platform to use for image signing and attestation by the attestor and want to remove the added attestation but I can't seem to find any documentation on how this is done or even if this is how is should be done.

I have seen the one for removal of the attestor but none on removing of deleting the attestation. I had added it using the following command:

Official documentation version:

```
gcloud container binauthz attestations create \
--project=$PROJECT_ID \
--artifact-url="${CONTAINER_PATH}@${DIGEST}" \ 
--attestor=${ATTESTOR} \  
--signature-file=./signature.pgp \ 
--public-key-id="$KEY_FINGERPRINT"
```

Online tutorial version:

```
gcloud beta container binauthz attestations create \ 
   --artifact-url="CONTAINER_PATH@DIGEST" \
   --attestor=ATTESTOT_ID \
   --attestor-project=PROJECT_ID \
   --signature-file=./signature.pgp \
   --pgp-key-fingerprint="KEY_FINGERPRINT"
```

but from a more recent documentation the `--attestor` should include the following `--attestor="projects/${ATTESTOR_PROJECT_ID}/attestors/${ATTESTOR}"` and unfortunately the tutorial I am following didn't use it this way and only added the `attestor_id` or `name`. So I want to remove this version and add new one but I am getting a conflict error

```
Resource in project [xxxx] is the subject of a conflict: occurrence ID "f5981e62-7b42-4f57-8486-b0d9518509fa" already exists in project
```

So how is it to be removed.

Update: documentation used to compare to online course: https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/making-attestations

Comment: Could you share the documentation that you have followed? Please clarify have you been able to delete the attestor but not the attestation and are you trying to create the new attestation without deleting the previous attestation, then you got the conflict error?

Comment: It's a pluralsight course and I did delete the attestor but when I tried to create another attestation the error still came up!

Comment: seems like somekind of underlying resources(the error messages indicates that) are still need to be deleted. Found some documentation on binary authorization where they have explained complete [tear down](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-binary-auth-demo/blob/master/README.md#tear-down) and [clean-up](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-binauthz-intro/#8).  It looks like apart from the attestor, we need to delete some other resources as well.

Comment: @digil very useful resource and I wonder why it's not available on the official documentation so the trick was to delete the attestor and then delete the note resource. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: For your reference, the command line option to delete an Attestor can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/binauthz/attestors/delete). Feel free to submit a [bug report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or 'Documentation feedback'(under 'SEND FEEDBACK' section in the [help](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/making-attestations) center article) inorder to share/report your ideas or issues connected with this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like somekind of underlying resources(the error messages indicates that) are still need to be deleted.

Found some documentation on binary authorization where they have explained complete  [tear down](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-binary-auth-demo/blob/master/README.md#tear-down) and [clean-up](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-binauthz-intro/#8). It looks like apart from the attestor, we need to delete some other connected resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official Google Cloud Documentation on Creating attestations](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/making-attestations#rest_3) and [project occurrences DELETE REST API method documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.occurrences/delete), I derived the **curl** command to delete a specific attestations:

```
curl "https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${ATTESTATION_PROJECT_ID}/occurrences/${OCCURRENCES_GUID}" \
  --request DELETE   --header "Content-Type: application/json"  \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
```

Assuming the executing user has containeranalysis.occurrences.delete permission as included in roles/containeranalysis.occurrences.editor, the response would be 200 with an empty json. I am not sure if the following header is required but at the time of my testing it wasn't.

```
-H "X-Goog-User-Project: ${ATTESTATION_PROJECT_ID}"
```

I have provided feedback to Google Cloud documentation to include my curl command above at [the official Google Cloud Documentation on Creating attestations](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/making-attestations#rest_3)